# Why componentDidUpdate trigger when prevState/prevProps are same as this.state/this.props

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, and its `componentDidUpdate` seems to trigger for no reason. It's a child component, has no state. Even though the `prevProps` and `this.props` are the exact same its triggering, is there any reason for this? I thought update should only trigger when there is a change in the `props`/`state`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> update should only trigger when there is a change in the props/state

No, React renders to VirtualDOM everything each time. But then it updates only changed properties in real DOM.

To avoid that you can use [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) or your custom comparation code in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks I want to avoid mixins as I hear they are deprecated. I am using `shouldComponentUpdate` now but I am having an issue on figuring out if all things in `prevProps` are same as that in in `this.props` may you please see - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36743571/1828637

Answer (score 7):

`componentDidUpdate()` is fired every time the parent component re-renders (and passes in new props). And in stateful components also whenever `setState()` is fired.

***Even if old `prevprops` and `this.props` are exactly the same, `componentDidUpdate()` is still fired if the parent component re-renders.***

If you want to prevent react to enter a render cycle, you should implement the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method, where you can compare new and old props.

Comment: Thanks very much. I want to accept your solution as well. I accepted the other as he had lower rep though. But I have a question. I'll post it now. May you please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36743571/1828637